# Add combobox to cell in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add combobox to datagrid, my code is

```
 <DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Catalog Number"  Width="1*"  />
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description"  Width="1*" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

I need something like: `<ComboBox  DataGridRow="1" DataGridColumn="1"/>`

Note: I want to add combobox to one specific cell

Comment: Is it an entire column or just one row?

Comment: I need combobox in specific cell

Comment: If you literally mean one cell instead of all cells in that column then I don't think you can do that with DataGrid - or at best it would hacky. Hopefully you want it for all cells in the column as per usual. [Find some examples online](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Easy-ComboBox-in-DataGrid-752d9d18)

Comment: @Crowcoder I need only one specific cell

Comment: @MilfyBerstein Perhaps update your question to specify that requirement. Otherwise people will assume you are looking for a combobox column type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to only have a combobox in one cell and not the entire column you would need to use a template column with a trigger to show the combo box.

```
<DataGrid>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Catalog Number"  Width="1*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding JobInfo.Jobname}">
                            <TextBlock.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsComboBox}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBlock.Style>
                        </TextBlock>

                        <ComboBox>
                            <ComboBox.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsComboBox}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </ComboBox.Style>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description"  Width="1*" />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this Code

<DataGrid Name="dg" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DGRows}" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"> 
            <DataGrid.Columns> 
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding RowDescription}" Header="Description"/> 

                <DataGridComboBoxColumn  SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ComboCollectionId}" 
                                         SelectedValuePath="ComboRowId" 
                                         DisplayMemberPath="ComboRowDescription" 
                                         Header="Combo Column"> 
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle> 
                        <Style TargetType="ComboBox"> 
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.ComboRows, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" /> 
                            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/> 
                        </Style> 
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle> 
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle> 
                        <Style TargetType="ComboBox"> 
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.ComboRows, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" /> 
                        </Style> 
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle> 
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn> 
            </DataGrid.Columns> 
        </DataGrid>
```